# Is there public OGC Catalog Service (CSW) available which lets ArcGIS for Desktop with CSW Client Add (WMS) To Map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, ogc, csw, csw-client

This is a follow on from a Question that I asked last year entitled [Is there a public OGC Catalog Service (CSW) available?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/is-there-a-public-ogc-catalog-service-csw-available).  That Question has an Accept-ed Answer but I would now like to expand upon the question slightly.

Is there a public OGC Catalog Service (CSW) available which serves URLs that can be bound to as *Live Data and Maps* by *ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2*?

I would like to learn of a CSW service URL (with its Profile specified) that I could use to Configure the [CSW Client of ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Geoportal-Server-Downloads) so that I can see it add a WMS service to ArcMap by using the Add to Map button rather than by using copy/paste of URLs.

A Comment on my Answer to [Is there an exhaustive, searchable catalog of all GIS web services (e.g. OGC WMS/WFS, REST, SOAP)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34775/is-there-an-exhaustive-searchable-catalog-of-all-gis-web-services-e-g-ogc-wms) says that it is possible but I do not recall ever being able to do it personally, including during tests I performed yesterday using the latest versions of ArcGIS for Desktop and its CSW Client.

---

After upgrading to ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop and @Luke resolving [Where to download CSW Client for ArcMap (ArcGIS for Desktop)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139105/where-to-download-csw-client-for-arcmap-arcgis-for-desktop) at that new version, I was able to conclude my test successfully.

I cannot comment on whether it now works at 10.2.x because I forgot to re-check before upgrading from 10.2.2 and my initial testing was at 10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL: http://www.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW

Profile: "GeoNetwork CSW 2.0.2 APISO"

Direct [link](http://www.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?service=CSW&request=GetRecordById&version=2.0.2&ElementSetName=full&OutputSchema=csw:IsoRecord&ID=ef83a32c-31e6-55c4-e044-00144fdd4fa6) to record highlighted in the screenshots below.

**CSW Client config:**

[image: CSW Client config]

**Search results:**

[image: Search results]

**Added to TOC:**

[image: Added to TOC]

Comment: @PolyGeo note that not all results from this CSW have map services that can be added as "Live Data and Maps"

Comment: but if I choose the one you illustrated then I'll be able to see one?  That's enough for my proof of concept purposes.

Comment: @PolyGeo yes that one has a wms.

Comment: Sorry to drop the ball on this.  I don't think I ever got back to it and have now upgraded to ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop where I am blocked from testing by http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139105/where-to-download-csw-client-for-arcmap  Hopefully, that will resolve quickly so that I can retest.