# Where to download CSW Client for ArcMap (ArcGIS for Desktop)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, esri-geoportal-server, csw, csw-client

I just tried to find and download the CSW Client for ArcMap so that I could use it with ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop to test an answer at [Is there public OGC Catalog Service (CSW) available which lets ArcGIS for Desktop with CSW Client Add (WMS) To Map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77567/is-there-public-ogc-catalog-service-csw-available-which-lets-arcgis-for-deskto)

I located a [Geoportal Server Downloads page on GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Geoportal-Server-Downloads) and clicked on the Desktop Clients for ArcGIS 10.2 link because there was not a link to Desktop Clients for ArcGIS 10.3.

When I tried to install it all the same I was blocked by a message saying:

> CSW Client for ArcGIS Desktop requires ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop CSW
>
> Client for ArcGIS Desktop will not be installed at this time.

[image]

Is there a CSW Client for ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop available for download anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the 10.3 Desktop Clients from the [Geoportal Server Downloads](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Geoportal-Server-Downloads) page on GitHub now ([#139](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/issues/139)).

I requested that it be built on [GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/issues/139) two days earlier.